# How to list photos by category in php

Tags: php

I have two mysql db tables, photos and album, I would like to list photos by album how do i do that ?

```
CREATE TABLE `album` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `album_name` varchar(95) NOT NULL,
 `album_desc` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `photos` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `album_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `thumb_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `photo_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the syntax but something like this

```
 SELECT * FROM photos GROUP BY album_id;
```

might do the trick.